# Unable to send message to USA numbers using Amazon SNS

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

This is my code for sending a message using Amazon SNS.

It is working fine when I tried with Indian numbers but when I tried with American numbers it failed. I want to fix it.

```
async sendMessage(testId: number) {

    require('dotenv').config();
    
    
    var mobileNo = +17866987580//dummy number
    
    var params = {
      Message: `A backflow test was completed successfully.`,
      PhoneNumber: mobileNo,
    };
    return new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010–03–31' })
      .publish(params)
      .promise()
      .then((message) => {
        console.log('Message SEND SUCCESS');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      });

}
```

Comment: How did it fail, what was the exception?

Comment: You can activate [Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch) to obtain more detailed information about message delivery failures.

Answer (score 0):

##### 1. First of all make sure you're no longer in the SNS sandbox:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-moving-to-production.html

##### 2. Make sure you've requested supported for SMS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport.html

##### 3. US specific requests to be made:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-long-code.html